# TRUE a checkbox, and start a background timer, then make TRUE the next two column of checkbox automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets, scripting

When I click TRUE a checkbox, then run a background timer, after 3 days will auto click TRUE the next two column of checkbox, else if the checkbox is FALSE next 2 column of checkbox is direct(no timer) to FALSE.

Please help, I can't fix this long time already...

I refer to this example: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3199678?hl=en

```
function onCheck()
{
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection();
  var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
  var date = new Date();
  var time = date.getTime();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(time,currentCell);
}

function autoCheck()
{
  var selection1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection();
  var currentCell1 = selection1.getCurrentCell();
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var nowDate = new Date();
  var nowDay = 3000; //milliseconds for 1 full day
  var r = currentCell1.getRow();
  //var c = currentCell1.getColumn();
  //var range = currentCell1.getRange(c,r);
  var keys = props.getKeys();
  for(var i in keys)
  {
    var time = parseInt(keys[i]);
    if(nowDate.getTime() - time > nowDay);
    {
    if(selection1.getCurrentCell("TRUE"))r+2.setValue("TRUE");
    }
    if(selection1.getCurrentCell("FALSE"))r+2.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

[Question Explain Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvSDB.png)
I added the picture to explain my question...Sorry...

Sorry bad English and poor on coding...
Please help me

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome.Please add all the relevant details to the question it self as the external content could be unavailable for future readers. Include the execution transcript and textual error if any occurs.

Comment: Welcome. We can't access the script editor of your spreadsheet. However you should include your script in your question; it is much easier for people to read.

Comment: Hi, sry about that, I was added the script in the question, Thank you.

Comment: You want to uncheck the following 2 rows checkbox 1 day after you click on one checkbox?

Comment: Hi, clicked the left side checkbox then after 3 days check to right side checkbox

Comment: Sorry, its next 2 column...my bad...

Comment: I was added the picture to explain my question...Sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an onEdit trigger to run a function that will save the value of the checked cell using the properties service [1] and it'll also create a time-based trigger [2]. The time-based trigger will run a function to uncheck [3] the 2 rows and it'll delete the no longer needed trigger.

Here is the code I tested:

```
function saveCheckedCell(e) {
  //Checks if the previous value was false (unchecked) and if the new value is true (checked)
  if(e.oldValue.toUpperCase() == "FALSE" && e.value.toUpperCase() == "TRUE") {
    var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection();
    var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell().getA1Notation();

    //Creates the trigger to call the autoCheck function after 3 days
    var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("autoCheck")
    .timeBased()
    .after(3 * 3600 * 24 * 1000)
    .create();

    var triggerId = trigger.getUniqueId();
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(triggerId, currentCell);    
  }
  else if(e.oldValue.toUpperCase() == "TRUE" && e.value.toUpperCase() == "FALSE") {
    var r = e.range;
    r.offset(0, 2).uncheck();    
  }
}

function autoCheck(e) {
  var triggerId = e.triggerUid;

  //Gets the recently checked cell
  var a1Notation = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(triggerId);
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(a1Notation);

  //Unchecks the 2 cells below the recently checked cell
  r.offset(0, 2).check();

  //Deletes the time trigger
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].getUniqueId() == triggerId) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
}  

//Run this function only once to create the onEdit trigger
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('saveCheckedCell')
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}
```

The first time you have to run the code directly from Apps Script so you can authorize the permissions. Run the createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() function and it'll create the script and prompt the oauth consent screen.

In case you need it, these are the scopes that you should have in the manifest file [4]:
["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#uncheck()

[4] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much!
But I got an error: ''TypeError: Cannot read property "oldValue" from undefined.''
what error is this?

Comment: I edited the code to use triggerIDs to be able to have several triggers at the same time which is needed to don't override the process each time you check a cell. Run the createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() function directly from Apps Script.

Comment: Now the code checks the checkbox 2 columns to the right. The error you're getting is because you're running the saveCheckedCell(e) directly from the editor and the `e` parameter is only provided when the function is ran by the trigger.

Comment: Thanks bro! It works! 
This code means day * hour * minutes * millisecond? 
`.after(3 * 72 * 4320 * 259200000)`

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I have edited that part to be 3 days now,  it's  days * seconds * hours * miliseconds (`3 * 3600 * 24 * 1000`)